# ERROR EN VISTA (TREE) Odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo

No me muestra en la vista tree los campos apellidos, numseguridad. Solo el nombre. Agrego modelos y vistas:

```
class centromedico_pacientes(models.Model): #rw by secretaria users, r doctores/enfermeros
_name = 'centromedico.pacientes'

name = fields.Char(string="Nombre", required=True)
apellidos = fields.Char(string="Apellidos", required=True)
numserguridad = fields.Integer(string="Número seguridad social", required=True)
cita = fields.One2many("centromedico.citas","cpaciente",string="Libros")
```

class centromedico_citas(models.Model): #rw by secretaria users, r doctores
    _name = 'centromedico.citas'

```
fconsulta = fields.Datetime(string="Fecha consulta", required=True)
cpaciente = fields.Many2one('centromedico.pacientes', string="Paciente")
```

Y esta sería la vista para el modelo centromedico_citas que es donde no me muestra bien el tree:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="centromedico.citas_tree"> 
  <field name="name">centromedico.citas.tree</field>
  <field name="model">centromedico.citas</field> 
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
      <field name="fconsulta"/>
      <field name="cpaciente">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="apellidos"/>
      </field>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="centromedico.citas_form">
  <field name="name">centromedico.citas.form</field>
  <field name="model">centromedico.citas</field> 
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form>
      <group> 
        <field name="fconsulta"/>
        <field name="cpaciente">
          <tree>
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="apellidos"/>
            <field name="numserguridad"/>
          </tree>
        </field>
      </group>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está en que estás metiendo una vista tree en una vista form, eso te debería de dar un error de XML, ahora si lo que quieres es agregar unos tabs la etiqueta es notebook y después pages.